# Finding limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Hi I'm having a lot of trouble with this: I need to find the limit of the following sequence:

$$
k \in \mathbb{N}, \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{k+1}}\left(k !+\frac{(k+1) !}{1 !}+\cdots+\frac{(k+n) !}{n !}\right)
$$
There's a hint that I should use the following formula:
$$
(1-q)\left(1+q+\cdots+q^{N}\right)=\left(1-q^{N+1}\right)
$$

Comment: Given limit seems like Riemann sum of integration of a function defined on $[0,1]$  .

Comment: It probably doesn't involve any integrals since we did reach that far in class.

Comment: I get $\dfrac1{k+1}$ by summing the terms as a binomial. But no use of the hint as far as I can see...

Comment: Answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562461/limit-of-a-sequence-might-be-related-to-cesaro-theorem